# Google app engine down: Server Error

Tags: google-app-engine

I built a system running on: http://www.hijgoo.com.tw and all the sudden, there was the following message and it did persist. I am using GAE SDK 1.7.2 with Python 2.7. Can anyone help?

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Comment: File "/base/data/home/apps/s~hijgoo1/1.364181539795484394/gaeutilities/sessions.py", line 1041, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(unicode(keyname))
KeyError: u'account'

Comment: Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMTLast-Modified: Fri, 28 Dec 12 11:47:00 UTCCache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0Pragma: no-cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a session that does not contain the key `account`, but your code assumes that it does.

The reason for this isn't easy to see without the actual code, but it sounds like a programming error.

Comment: That's strange. My program runs OK on the GAE SDK, and it runs on the GAE for some time before the system crashes. The statement I used to create a session is "self.session['account'] = account" and the statement used for checking a session is "account = self.session['account']". Is something wrong with that?

Comment: @Yuan-LiangTang The second (`account = self.session['account']`) will give that error if `account` is not set. In other words, is there any way you can get to that line without `account` being previously set in the session?

Comment: I didn't quite get you, probably because of the same 'account' names. Let me rephrase the statement: I create a session using "self.session['account'] = username" and check the existence of a session by "username = self.session['account']" Anything wrong with that? Thank you.

Comment: Where are you storing the session? If it's in memcache it's quite possible that it's expired by the time you look for it again.